# SPF from neutral to positive

Tags: email, internet, google, domain

I need to be able to configure SPF rule for my domain. Problem is that I can normally receive all the emails. But when I send to some recipients they receive it as spam. 
In the mail failure delivery I always see SPF as neutral.

How can I change this settings? I found a Microsoft tool program and I get something like this: `v=spf1 a mx mx:mail.code2future.com +all`
Where do I insert this? I have cPanel Pro 1.0 (RC1)

Thank you

EDIT:

This is the picture:
[image]

Comment: SPF records go in the DNS for your domain; is your cPanel controlling your DNS or is it managed elsewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, that SPF line is completely useless. The `+all` on the end means anyone can send e-mail on behalf of your domain, and it should be considered authentic. Further, that SPF record looks wrong in all sorts of ways, though I can't be sure without knowing more about your environment.

Some servers will even hold this against you. On the servers I run, if your SPF doesn't end in "-all" then you get marked as spam because you're too lazy or ignorant to setup a SPF record correctly. <sub>Sorry for the terse language, but 2 points for honesty...</sub>

So, once you've got a reasonable SPF record, you need to create a new DNS record of the type TXT, with the contents of that SPF record. The "address" of the DNS record should be blank, default, or "@", depending on how you're system works.

---

**Update:**
A couple common configurations just to get you started:

1. You have 1 mail server. It's configured to receive mail for your domain (including the MX record)
   `v=spf1 mx -all`
2. You have 1 "normal" mail server, and a web server that sends e-mail too (notifications or etc)
   `v=spf1 mx ip:1.2.3.4 -all` (where the IP address is that of the web server)
3. You have completely separate inbound and outbound servers. The outbound have A Records.
   `v=spf1 a -all`
4. You're using a hosted e-mail solutions, such as gmail or something your hosting provides.
   `v=spf1 include:get.address.from.your.host.com -all`
   `v=spf1 include:aspmx.googlemail.com -all` (for GMail/Google Apps/etc hosted e-mail only)

[The Microsoft Sender ID Framework SPF Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/) is an excellent resource for generating records. You do have to read each option carefully; garbage-in garbage-out.

Comment: I would pay serious attention to what Chris said about using `-all`.  The standard itself, at http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax, defines `+all` as "The domain owner thinks that SPF is useless and/or doesn't care".

Comment: How can I form such SPF? and where to write that?

Comment: See update. The record still goes in a TXT DNS entry.

Comment: I have used this solution `v=spf1 mx ip:1.2.3.4 -all` and now it's working as it should. is this safe solution?

Comment: Yep, that's good. As long as you didn't literally use "1.2.3.4", and replaced it with the address of your server.

Comment: hmm funny thing happens when I send email from ipad I get error from mail delivery failure but when I try with outlook everything is good. I'll try your first example without IP

Comment: this is my what I get `Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of x.x@x.com does not designate xx.xx.xx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xxx;` what should I do? please help

Comment: First, know that Google will cache your SPF record for a day or so; if you make rapid changes they're likely to not get picked up. I'm getting the feeling that you're not a system administrator... This really isn't that hard to figure out. If the mail server (xx.xx.xx.xxx) has a MX record in your domain (x.com) then use the 1st record example. If it's not an MX, but does have a forward DNS name then use the 3rd example.

Comment: Can you please check my picture what I have uploaded and tell me what to do because nothing seems to be working with option 1 and option 2

Comment: That helps a little. You don't have a MX record, so "mx" will not do anything. Not having any inbound servers you could say that inbound and outbound are completely separate, that's option #3. Also, you may want to look into CNAME records, it would simplify your configuration.

Comment: Where can I find CNAME records? So option #3 should work in here?